# How to return exception to Action function through an inside function?

Tags: java, scala, exception, future, concurrent.futures

I have a simple action function:

```
def someActionFunc() = Action.async { request =>

 myService.doSomething1().map { res =>
        logger.debug(res.getMessageId)
        Ok(res.getMessageId)
      }.recover {
        case ex =>
          logger.error(s"fail:", ex)
          BadRequest(s"fail with error: ${ex.getMessage}")
      }
}
```

`doSomething1` returns a `Future`, and in `doSomething1` I'm calling some other function `doSomething2` that returns some object and the exception happened there, but I don't know how to return the error that happened in `doSomething2` through `doSomething1` to the action function (`someActionFunc`) cause I want to return the user `fail with error: my reason`

So I tried in `doSomething2` to do something like:

```
def doSomething2(someCondition: Boolean) = {
      if (someCondition){
        throw new RuntimeException("my reason")
      }
    }
```

but I get thrown out, how can I return the error properly to the user throw the action function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, a `Future[T]` is really just a [`Try[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Try.html) that takes some time to complete. In turn, a `Try[T]` can *only* be a `Success[T]` or `Failure[T]` - where a [`Failure[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Failure.html) is really just a wrapper around an exception.

The reason why your error handling chain isn't working is that you're circumventing Scala's functional style of handling (based **entirely upon return values from functions**) and instead using the Java-style `throw` idiom - which of course still works in the JVM, but not Scala-idiomatically.

If you rewrite `doSomething2` like this:

```
def doSomething2(someCondition: Boolean):Future[Int] = {
  if (someCondition){
    Future.failed(new RuntimeException("my reason"))
  } else {
    Future.succesful(42)
  }
}
```

you'll get the idiomatic Scala error-handling you're looking for.

Some things to note:

- I use the `failed()` and `successful()` methods on the [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.3/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$) *object* to conveniently construct the necessary wrappers around my possible outcomes
- Although I *create* an `Exception` instance, I *never* `throw` it
- I've explicitly stated the return type of `doSomething2` to help the compiler ensure correctness - what was the return type of `doSomething2` before? `Unit`?